# Where is "Show Snippet Highlighting" in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio when a snippet is inserted the code contains highlighted replacement variables which disappear when the user starts editing outside the snippet area. In Visual Studio 2012 I used context menu option `Show Snippet Highlighting`. I cannot find it any more in Visual Studio 2017. I is mentioned in book [Professional Visual Studio 2017 By Bruce Johnson](https://books.google.cz/books?id=RKA6DwAAQBAJ&pg=SA7-PA36&lpg=SA7-PA36&dq=%22show%20snippet%20highlighting%22%202017&source=bl&ots=zPIr9N-nBx&sig=Xp2fOK4LeHhnpmiH4GoBBYyntYM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_zYLQxpzfAhVjhOAKHbSCD7cQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22show%20snippet%20highlighting%22%202017&f=false).

Was this feature removed? Is it on some hidden place? Is it configurable? 
[image]

Comment: It no longer exists.  No doubt a victim of the Roslyn rewrite at VS2015, the C# IDE did not have the command.  Watch out for books like that, the publisher just slaps a new title on the old book, might ask the author to mention a few new features, but doesn't proof-read the existing text well enough.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was afraid of that. I found the book while looking for any clear statement whether the feature is present or not.